# Trivial HTML site not showing an image

Tags: html, image, markup

This one got me really stumped. I have stripped a problematic website of basically *everything*, being left with the most trivial barebone site you can imagine:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <title>Test site</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <img​ src​="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

...and yet, the `img` tag doesn't work. I get an empty website - and the W3 validator throws errors like `Element img​ not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`. What am I doing wrong? I have no idea what can be causing issues in a markup that consists of basically no elements other than the `img` and the ones required.

Comment: Are you giving w3validator url or content? If url then it might be loading from cache perhaps

Comment: You made a typo. You have an (invisible) `U+200B : ZERO WIDTH SPACE [ZWSP]` immediately after the `img` and before the space that is supposed to be between `img` and `src`.

Comment: okay, so after removing typo invisible `U+200B : ZERO WIDTH SPACE [ZWSP]` is it still a problem or we can remove the question !

Comment: @Quentin - oh my, that's precisely it, thanks so much :O How do you even go about finding a problem like this when it's invisible?

Comment: @Quentin also if you want to promote your comment to an answer, I'll of course happily mark it as the solution!

Comment: Typo questions aren't useful in the long term. They should be closed / deleted not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="W3Schools.com" 
style="width:104px;height:142px;">
</body>
</html>
```

As mentioned in the comment, there were 2 invisible characters after img and src.

I used text-compare to figure out this, please refer the attached screenshot.

[image]